# Google Spreadsheet App Design

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet based application that uses javascript macros to update a database and email the results to users.  I want system admins to be able to view the spreadsheet and perform update and mail tasks by calling macros, but I do not want them to be able to modify the spreadsheet directly.

I could give them view access to the spreadsheet and use a form to perform their tasks.  However,  the forms are public and one is warned not to use passwords in forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are not using google apps with a domain but with generic email address  in gmail.com (otherwise you should be able to control the name of the person who is answering the form).
The solution can be to build your form in google apps script so you'll retrieve named answers.

Comment: I am using generic addresses.  Is this method secure? Will it not be compromised by email spoofing?  I will try this and method and incorporate a password check also.  Its not exactly the crown jewels I am trying to protect, just trying to prevent someone corrupting the spreadsheet by accident.